# sed remove up to a certain point, including the pattern itself

Tags: bash, sed

We have a string like the following:

```
ash oak brock misty oak oak james oak jesse misty
```

We need to remove everything up to the nth instance of `oak` in the string above and also remove the pattern itself.

So, `sed` with `1` would show:

```
 brock misty oak oak james oak jesse misty
```

`sed` with `2` would show:

```
 oak james oak jesse misty
```

`sed` with `3` would show:

```
 james oak jesse misty
```

`sed` with `4` would show:

```
 jesse misty
```

We use BSD `sed` but also can use GNU `sed`. Thanks

We tried `sed $number',/^.*oak/{s/oak//}'` but this didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'H;g;s/\n//g;s/oak/\n/2;/.*\n/{s///;:a;n;ba};d' file
```

Append the current line to the hold space and then replace the current line by the contents of the hold space. Remove all newlines and replace the occurrence of the desire string by a newline. If the current line contains a newline, remove everything from the start of the current line up to and including the introduced newline and then fetch and print the remainder of the file. Otherwise delete the current line and repeat.

Comment: Thank you, this preserves the space after the pattern which is what we need

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is not the right tool for this because there is no support for lazy quantifier in BRE or ERE.

As an alternative, you may use `perl` with more robust regex engine:

```
$> s='ash oak brock misty oak oak james oak jesse misty'

$> perl -pe 's/^(.*?\boak\b){2}\h*//' <<< "$s"
oak james oak jesse misty

$> perl -pe 's/^(.*?\boak\b){1}\h*//' <<< "$s"
brock misty oak oak james oak jesse misty

$> perl -pe 's/^(.*?\boak\b){3}\h*//' <<< "$s"
james oak jesse misty
```